# Why is cmp $0xffffffffffffffff, %edi used in assembly?

Tags: assembly

While I was studying assembly code, I saw below code segment. I am a bit confused.

```
mov $0x0, %ecx
lea  0x3(%rdi), %eax
cmp $0xffffffffffffffff, %edi    ; ???
cmovle %eax, %rdi
```

I have marked line by ???. I don't understand why that line is used in assembly code?

assembly : x86 64 bit

EDIT: I haven't any comparison in my code. For this reason, I wonder why ?

Note: I haven't find relevant title for that question. help and inform me if you find one. So, I can change

Comment: It looks like a comparison against `-1`.

Comment: Can you show us the code that produces this?

Comment: @Mysticial, I can't. Forgive me. I took only question sheet before leaving home not code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it compares the register `%edi` with the constant `$0xffffffffffffffff` which is actually the constant `-1`

Comment: It should be stressed that it's -1 only for a 64-bit two's compliment value.

Comment: ... and then the following instruction (CMOVLE) copies the contents of EAX into RDI on the condition that EDI was Less than or Equal to -1 (it can check that because the CMP instruction sets the results of comparison in the FLAGS register). Btw, I'm a bit surprised to see several operand size mismatches (RDI & EAX in LEA, 64-bit -1 & EDI in CMP, and EAX & RDI in CMOV). I'd expect all of them 64-bit or 32-bit. Is the above (dis)assembly correct?

Comment: Three errors in four lines, @OP you need to be more careful when copying text